# How do I use symbolic links in Apache/XAMPP?

Tags: apache, xampp, symlink

I am trying to link from the htdocs directory in my XAMPP directory to my home directory (I am using Ubuntu). The permissions of the directory of my website are drwxrwxr-x. 
I also added the FollowSymLinks option for htdocs in httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes

AllowOverride All

Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Nevertheless, I still get a error 403 when i try to open my website. 
This is the message in error.log :

```
[Thu Dec 06 22:53:28.874813 2012] [core:error] [pid 7553] [client 127.0.0.1:32999] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /opt/lampp/htdocs/benjamin/website-paul
```

Do you have any idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You must identify where you want to allow from -- who is allowed to follow the link. This could be an IP, IP range, domain, or all.  Also, even though you are likely to allow from all, it is good practice to set allow order.

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```